# When I run this process, it pushes all others out of RAM. Is there any way to prevent this?

Tags: windows-8, memory, 64-bit, process, pagefile

I like to leave my browser, email, and other applications running while I'm gaming. Now that I'm running a 64-bit version of Windows with 16 GB of RAM, I can do this easily, and even switch between a running game and other applications without any issues. Except for one game (Battlefield 2).

After monitoring memory use for a while, I've observed the following:

1. When I start BF2, physical memory use actually drops significantly.
2. At the same time, the amount of physical memory used by all other applications drops to almost zero.
3. If I switch from BF2 to another application, there's a long pause, during which it appears that Windows is pulling the application's memory back from the paging file.
4. Ditto when I close BF2 (a delay when I try to use another already-running application).

I haven't run into any other applications (or games) that do this. Normally, I can switch between games and applications without any delays. Changing the size of the paging file doesn't make any difference.

I'm assuming that this is something the BF2 developers did intentionally, but is there any way to override the behaviour?

Comment: Do you have an hard drive or ssd?

Comment: Are you running it in fullscreen, windowed fullscreen, or windowed mode?

Comment: @cybernard: all hard drives.

Comment: @TheKB: BF2 supports fullscreen and windowed, but not windowed fullscreen. It doesn't seem to make any difference which mode I choose.

Comment: Could you run it in compatibility mode for Windows XP or Vista and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @boot13  hard drives manage around 100-130mb/s read and a lot less writing speeding.  SSD manage 500mb/s read and 200-500mb/s write depending on capacity and manufacturer.   It may not 100% fix it, but it will make the long pause orders of magnitude less.

Comment: @TheKB: changed compatibility for the EXE file (not the shortcut), but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @cybernard: thanks for the tip, but I was hoping to determine the reason for this behaviour, and - if possible - prevent it from happening.

Comment: Check for any application settings specifically ruled, such as the one in AMD Catalyst 3D Application settings that affects application usage for performance.

Comment: @AlgorithmBreaker: interesting suggestion. I checked the NVidia control panel, and did find specific settings for bf2.exe, but they are all set to use the global settings.